# How to inherit seekbar style from black theme when using holo?

Tags: android, seekbar

I was using black theme and have created a customized seekbar. No I had to switch to holo theme but really wanted the look of theme.black seekbar back.
i tried

```
<style name="W_SeekBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Black.SeekBar">

    </style>
```

but that gives me an error...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no Widget.Black, just use this:

```
<SeekBar style="@android:style/Widget.SeekBar"
```